# Python: How to convert a hexadecimal string to a normal string?

Tags: python, string, ascii

I have a string of the following form

\xNN\xNN\xNN\xNN…

- N can be any digit from 0 to 9. For example:

```py
str = "\x41\x42\x43"
```

- \xNN is a hexadecimal number that represents a character according to ASCII code.

Is there a simple way to convert this type of string to a normal string? For example "\x41\x42\x43" is equivalent to "ABC".

Answer (score 1):

How about

```py
>>> s = b"\x41\x42\x43"
>>> print(s)
b'ABC'
```

Or

```py
>>> s = "\x41\x42\x43"
>>> print(s.encode())
b'ABC'
```